# Problem with using a fixture in pytest parametrize

Tags: pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

What is the correct syntax to use my_list fixture with parametrize in pytest?
I would like test_item() to be run 5 times (based on the list returned by my_list fixture)

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_list():
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("item", my_list())
def test_item(item):
    print(item)
    assert item < 6
```

I tried also this, but did not succeed:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_list():
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("item", "my_list")
def test_item(item, request):
    item = request.getfixturevalue("item")
    print(item)
    assert item < 6
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a `fixture` directly, `my_list()` should be a regular function. If you still want it as a `fixture` extract the functionality to another function

```
def my_list_imp():
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


@pytest.fixture
def my_list():
    return my_list_imp()


@pytest.mark.parametrize("item", my_list_imp())
def test_item(item):
    print(item)
    assert item < 6
```

Output

```
example.py::test_item[1] PASSED                                          [ 20%]1

example.py::test_item[2] PASSED                                          [ 40%]2

example.py::test_item[3] PASSED                                          [ 60%]3

example.py::test_item[4] PASSED                                          [ 80%]4

example.py::test_item[5] PASSED                                          [100%]5
```

Comment: You are right. May be I do not need to use a fixture. In my case my_list and test_item are part of a class TestParent. I want to create a new class TestChild in another file and override only my_list function to return different list of elements. Do you think this is possible (with or without fixtures)?

Comment: @Jaxx `@pytest.mark.parametrize` is executed in test collection time and is not in the class scope, so you can't really override `my_list` as a parameter.

Comment: I mark your answer as solution to this question and I will open another question with more details on the related issue